# Can I issue a lawsuit against my city for having unsafe air quality?

Tags: civil-law, environmental, public-law

I live in Ljubljana, the capital city of Slovenia(EU).

In many parts of my city, there are many times a high level of air pollution because of cars, especially in the area where I'm currently living. I don't have a car so for my daily
chores I usually walk great distances to get to my destination... While I'm walking, I can smell the horrendous smell that cars are producing especially during the rush hours when many streets get blocked... My nose hurts from all the smell and I'm usually taking a longer route because of that. The air measurement station where the city air quality is measured is in a position that does not reflect the actual air quality.

So my question is:

If I provide proof that cars are violating safe air quality standards every day in many city areas... Can I then issue a lawsuit against my city for violating air quality standards?

Comment: Does the city own the cars?

Comment: @MichaelHall The city is legally responsible for providing clean water to its residents, and for removing garbage from bins and so on... In my view, the city is also responsible for clean air, and is responsible for providing solutions to car problems. The land on which cars are driven is owned by the city and if the city allows the cars to drive on them then the city is responsible for the by-products coming from the cars.

Comment: @UrošJarc you stated that, 'the city is...responsible for clean air,' which appears to be an assumption you've made, but is there something to legally base it on? Such an assertion seems like it might have ground in a national constitution or major piece of environmental legislation.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical Yes this is the assumption that I have made, I have made research on laws regarding air quality, and we have some regulations regarding air quality... But the regulations are more focused on the national level not on specific city areas. For example we have a regulation that county officials must notify residents when bad air particles are going to be present in the air...

Comment: I don't disagree that the city can exert influence over local air quality by enacting restrictions, but the other services you describe them as providing differ dramatically because the city cannot provide air.  It is all around us.  Restrictions on automobiles affect business and individuals, some of whom may may be less sensitive, or value air quality less than you do.  The city answers to all residents and every action carries a price tag.

Comment: @MichaelHall Yes I agree that city can't provide clean air because there can't be a city service that could provide clean air... That would be impossible... But the city can exert influence on removing or creating solutions that could make air pollutants lower in certain areas... If there is area of city where the air pollutants is in danger zone regarding air safety... Then this is a problem that needs to be solved... But whose responsibility is that... I think its a city responsibility?

Comment: @MichaelHall If there are parts of the city where air quality is so bad that would affect the resident's health, then what can an individual like me do to make a change?

Comment: It's outside the scope of this site, but there is strength in numbers so your first step might be finding like minded citizens to organize.  In parallel, if your city council and mayor are democratically elected they have an obligation to answer to their constituents.  Try contacting them, attend city council meetings if they are public, engage with the local media to spread the word of your initiative to clean up the air.  Usually lawsuits are a last resort when other means have failed, or there is true negligence rather than a more libertarian policy.  Good luck!

Comment: In the end this boils down to a question of *Standing* - who can bring a lawsuit or not

Comment: @MichaelHall Thank you so much for your advice, I really appreciate your time! I confess that I have a biased view towards the problem since this affects me personally, that's why I wanted to get input from more people. Thank you again!

Comment: There were law suits like this in Germany, and as far as I remember, with some success.

Comment: @Arno Can you provide some sources, I would love to know more about it and how law suits work out at the end.

Comment: Maybe some examples can be found at https://climatecasechart.com/